# Qt show windows sequentially

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

I'm working on a Python Qt application which starts with a login window. After the login, I want to show the normal application window. As a test, I tried to show the AuthWindow (the login window) twice. The desired effect is for the login window to open once, I close it, then the second opens, etc. What actually happens it that the first opens, I close it, and the program exits.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

from AuthWindow import AuthWindow

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AuthWindow()
    w.show()
    w = AuthWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's the code for AuthWindow:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class AuthWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    User, Admin = range(2)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Login')
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.username = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.password = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        vbox.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Username'))
        vbox.addWidget(self.username)
        vbox.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Password'))
        vbox.addWidget(self.password)

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Login')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.loginClicked)

        hbox.addLayout(vbox)
        hbox.addWidget(btn)

        self.password.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)

    def loginClicked(self, ev):
        auth = self.checkLogin()
        print(auth)

    def checkLogin(self):
        username = self.username.text()
        password = self.password.text()
        print(username)
        print(password)
        # login logic will go here...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that show() allows the programme to continue; you should use exec_() to halt the code until the window is closed. So if you put:

```
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AuthWindow()
    w.exec_()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The second authwindow won't be created until the first one is closed.

Comment: Wow, that was a lot simpler that it seemed. I had come back here to post a kludgy solution I found, in which I overwrote the w.closeEvent function with lambda x : w.show(). Thanks a lot. I would up vote, but I don't have enough rep.